# Building mind map of software code

Tags: mind-mapping

as I was looking into mind mapping software, I came across one that claimed to build mind maps of written code showing the interconnections.

I don't remember which program this wss.anf can't find that article I was reading.

Anyone know of mind mapping software that can do this?

Thanks